# tomcat proxy error

Tags: tomcat, proxy

I encounter proxy error in my app and the log shows a lot of this.`Jan 28, 2011 12:24:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:607)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:196)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:112)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:125)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:118)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:179)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:116)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:76)
        at org.apache.jsp.pieChart_jsp._jspService(pieChart_jsp.java:142)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:331)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:151)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:874)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)`

Can't figure out the exact problem. Guess it will be with pieChart.jsp. Pls help me.

Answer (score 0):

Typically - I believe this occurs when you have closed the stream - but then you tried to write more to the buffer. For example:

`<%
out.print(myChartData);
out.close();
%>`

What happens in the JSP compiler will turn it into a servlet like this;

`out.print(myChartData);
out.close();
out.println("\r\n)"; 
out.println("\r\n)";`

And there will be as many \r\n prints as are in the jsp.

The easy workaround is to do this:
`<%
out.print(myChartData);
out.close();
if (myChartData!=null) {
  return;
}
%>`

In which case - there will be no extra prints after the close;